# Alternative way to build a list until predicate is satisfied?

Tags: lisp, racket

Here is my way of building a fibonacci sequence as a list whose values do not exceed *x*:

```
(define (fibs-upto x)
  (for/list ([i (in-naturals)]
             #:break (> (fib i) x))
            (fib i)))
```

Is there another, maybe cleaner way of doing this without using `#:break`, and without using `#lang lazy` to build an infinite lazy list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in which `(fib i)` is evaluated only once.

```
(define (fibs-upto x)
  (for*/list ([i     (in-naturals)]
              [fib-i (in-value (fib i))]
              #:break (> fib-i x))
    fib-i))
```

But it might be easier to read a standard loop:

```
(define (fibs-upto x)
  (define (loop i)
    (define fib-i (fib i))
    (if (> fib-i x)
        '()
        (cons fib-i (loop (+ i 1)))))
  (loop 0))
```

That said, it is important that `fib` cache previously computed values for the above solutions to be `O(n)`.

UPDATE

A version using `sequence-map`:

```
(define (fibs-upto x)
  (for/list ([y (sequence-map fib (in-naturals))]
             #:break (> y x))
    y))
```

Comment: I like this type of standard loop.

Comment: @bitrauser FWIW I added a version using `sequence-map`

Answer (score 1):

if you just want a list of Fibonacci numbers, you can e.g.

```
(define (fib-upto limit)
  (let loop ([fibs '(1 1)])
    (let ((fn (+ (first fibs) (second fibs))))
      (if (> fn limit)
          (reverse fibs)
          (loop (cons fn fibs))))))
;; e.g.:
(fib-upto 100)
'(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89)
```

If you want to know some idiomatic way of building lists with stop-condition, take a look at unfold (or unfold-right though you rather want unfold) -- http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FoldUnfoldMap

Answer (score 0):

Being that you posted this in racket... This may be a solution to the problem, but I did change one part of it which is easy work around if it is a problem. I hope this helps

// i = number to start at, x = number to go up to

```
(define (fibs-upto i x)
  (cond
    [(> (fib i) x) empty]
    [else (cons (fib i)(fibs-upto (+ i 1) x))]))
```

Workaround

```
(define (fibs-upto x)
  (fibs-help 0 x))

(define (fibs-help i x)
  (cond
    [(> (fib i) x) empty]
    [else (cons (fib i)(fibs-help (+ i 1) x))]))
```

Comment: Are you using a strange implementation of `fib` that returns a procedure? If not calling it like a procedure `(ans)` would halt the program...

Comment: @Sylwester I added that last minute, didn't really check if it works, I'm used to not being allowed to use define or let/set..

Comment: Your new `fibs-upto` and `fibs-help` functions re-calculate `(fib i)`. You should put the `(define ans (fib i))` local definitions back. You just needed to write `ans` instead of `(ans)`. (Remember that parentheses mean function application in Racket)